# How to insert records in relation when the statements is in oposite order using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I'm having an issue while trying to insert 2 records in a relation using the following statement:

```
Insert INTO [Table] (Id, ParentId, Name) Values (2, 1, 'Child');
Insert INTO [Table] (Id, ParentId, Name) Values (1, NULL, 'Parent');
```

I know that if I insert the Parent record first it will work, but the problem is that I can not do in my application.

I've tried to add them into a single transaction using BEGIN TRANSACTION but nothing changed.

The error that I'm getting is

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "..."
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't. if you have a foreign key, then the parent record **MUST** be inserted first. otherwise it's impossible to insert the child record, because there's no parent to point it at. that being said, you can temporarily disable foreign keys, but that's horrible bad practice and should never be done except in situations like loading backup dumps.

Comment: switch insert's order

Answer (score 0):

Updating ParentId afterwards

```
Insert INTO [Table] (Id, ParentId, Name) Values (2, NULL, 'Child');
Insert INTO [Table] (Id, ParentId, Name) Values (1, NULL, 'Parent');
update [Table] set ParentId=1 where Id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you can't add the parent first for whatever reason, but how about adding them simultaneously?

```
insert [Table] (Id, ParentId, Name) values 
    (2, 1, 'Child'),
    (1, NULL, 'Parent');
```

You won't run afoul of the constraint this way. If you absolutely *must* add the child first for whatever reason, then @vercelli's answer seems like the way to go.